# Calculate characters that fit a fixed rect TextView

Tags: ios, nsstring, uitextview

I have seen here people needing to calculate the size of the NSString given a size but I need to do the opposite.

Given a specified rect (or fixed UITextView, or multiline UILabel, no scrolling) I need to know:

- if it managed to show all the chars of my NSString
- if not, what is the last char shown

So that I can display the remaining text in another UITextView (of course if I could use a single UITextView I would not have this problem).

At first it seems a simple thing to do, but actually I am not finding a way, intuitively I think I could use either UITextView's:

```
textView.contentSize.height;
```

or NSString's:

```
sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:
```

or a combination of the two, but I need to be precise and those methods do not help me in telling what is the last character that managed to fit the visible area of the UITextView.

Not sure if this is actually possible, but is a requirement of my client who thinks programming iOS is like printing a newspaper and expects to be able to format text around an image....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe get the maximum height of one line of text from a one character long string.

If you use that with sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode: then you should be able to know if your text runs onto more than one line (if the cgsize height is greater than the height of one line of text).

In order to find out the last character (or word) you would have to loop around the length of the string adding characters (or words) as you go and checking for when the cgsize height increases to add a new line, this will give you the character point when to split into multiple strings ( for multiple fields/labels/textviews ) or when to insert line breaks into the text ( if using a single multi-line textview or label ).

I hope you find an easier way...

Comment: Yes, I thought about this too, but this is crazy, maybe someone has a better idea, the text might be very long and I need to be correct at the very char.